# Rerender region containing fields and markup without using rich:panel?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I've got a command button that should rerender some specific region with AJAX.

```
<a4j:commandButton ajaxSingle="true" actionListener="#{myListener}"
    reRender="ext" value="myButton" />
```

As long as the region is defined as

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="ext" layout="none">
   <rich:panel rendered="#{isPanelRendered}">
      ...
   </rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

it's working. But unfortunately I can't use `rich:panel` since it's creating an ugly border that I can't override with CSS.

But when changing to

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="ext" layout="none" rendered="#{isPanelRendered}">
      ...
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Also

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="ext" layout="none">
   <h:panelGrid rendered="#{isPanelRendered}">
      ...
   </h:panelGrid>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

isn't working.

How can I rerender my region, that contains fields and markup, without a `rich:panel` tag?

Comment: Using the `<h:panelGrid>` should work. Or did you mean with "isn't working" that it also shows a border? Try `<h:panelGroup>` instead of `<h:panelGrid>` then.

Comment: No. Unfortunately it's not refreshing. As soon as I'm switchin to rich:panel it works. But I also need AJAX functionality. I hope that `<h:panelGrid>` can provide that.

Comment: `rich:panel` is functionally not the same as `h:panelGrid`, but more as `h:panelGroup`. However, that shouldn't matter. It should work equally good as shown in your last code snippet (only if you fix that typo).

Comment: I've tried it now with `h:panelGroup`. On page startup, when `#{isPanelRendered}` is `true`, it rendered correctly. Then I send the AJAX request and it won't get rerendered respectivley hidden. Again, when switching the tag to `rich:panel` it'S working without flwas.

Comment: Try replacing `<a4j:outputPanel id="ext">` by `<h:panelGroup id="ext">`.

Comment: Doesn't work. :-( Btw: The panel is embedded inside an `<h:form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the style of the `rich:panel` after searching on the web I find out this:

```
<style>
    .rich-panel{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .rich-panel-body{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

And you can forget about that ugly border you dislike.

Comment: Where do I have to insert this?

Comment: You can copy the code and place it at the beginning of your page. If you want something more elaborate, you can create a style.css file and add it in your pages like this:<a4j:loadStyle src="/Resources/style.css" />